# Speed of waves in vacuum

Tags: general-relativity, waves, spacetime, speed-of-light, vacuum

All electromagnetic waves travel at speed of light in vacuum. Gravitional waves also travel at speed of light.
 I am having this vague notion that all waves in vacuum must travel at speed of light.
Is there any theorem like that?
If yes, please elaborate.
If not, please give some counterexamples.

Comment: What types of waves do you know, except gravitational and electromagnetic, which can travel through a vacuum?

Comment: I don't know any other. But I was just wondering if it were possible for a wave to travel at subliminal speed in vacuum. And if not, is this mere coincidence.

Comment: For EMW it is an established experimental fact. For the others it is a hypothesis with some experimental support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All zero mass particles travel at the speed of light in vacuum is not *a theorem*, but a result of imposing special relativity on the description of particles in quantum mechanics.

Electromagnetic waves are emergent from zillions of photons, and the same would be true for gravitational waves , emergent from zillions of gravitons, once gravity is definitively quantized.

In the standard model of particle physics before symmetry breaking , all particles have  zero mass, acquiring mass by the mechanisms as the Higgs mechanism of symmetry breaking for the  electroweak case. So in the [cosmological models](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/timlin.html#c1%22), before electroweak symmetry breaking one could have the [table of particles](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/00/Standard_Model_of_Elementary_Particles.svg/300px-Standard_Model_of_Elementary_Particles.svg.png) at zero mass, and in this sense the emergent "radiations" would travel at the speed of light in vacuum. The same for GUTS symmetry breaking. By construction as long as special relativity holds.